# multiple PDF (probability density function) curves along one axis within one plot

Tags: matlab

I have lots of particles in a box, coordinates *x,y,z* and diameter *d* of those in a data-file.

I can plot the PDF for a single x-position (particles in one plane), no problem. But what I would like to do is to plot PDFs of particle size in a few positions along the x-direction, as I sketched in the photo.

[image]

I guess one can do this by rescaling and shifting the different curves, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to go?

Comment: Check `subplot` if you need different axes as in your sketch, or `hold` to have them all in the same pair of axes

Comment: What you want are violin plots!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use a single plot with the `hold on` triggered.
Let's see an example. Let me generate 3 normal distributions (for the sake of demo):

```
pdf1=makedist('Normal',1,2);
pdf2=makedist('Normal',2,3);
pdf3=makedist('Normal',3,4);

v1=pdf(pdf1,[-10:10])+1;    % x1 = 1
v2=pdf(pdf2,[-10:10])+1.5;  % x2 = 1.5
v3=pdf(pdf3,[-10:10])+2;    % x3 = 2
```

So we have three PDFs with their respective values evaluated in range [±10] and shifted by values `1`, `1.5` and `2` (respectively).
Now we can open a figure and plot the three PDFs keeping in mind that since you have them in "vertical" position, the x-values must be on the y-axis and viceversa.

```
figure(1)
plot(v1,[-10:10],'r'); grid on;
hold on; plot(v2,[-10:10],'g');
hold on; plot(v3,[-10:10],'b');
legend('PDF_1','PDF_2','PDF_3');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('d_{particle}');
```

and if you want also to add the dashed lines you can complete the code above with

```
hold on; plot(1*ones(1,length([-10:10])),[-10:10],'r--');
hold on; plot(1.5*ones(1,length([-10:10])),[-10:10],'g--');
hold on; plot(2*ones(1,length([-10:10])),[-10:10],'b--');
```

And this code will return
[image]

Comment: That's kindof what I had in mind when I mentioned rescaling and shifting, although scaling might not be necessary. Great example, thanks Alessiox !

Comment: Rescaling is indeed not necessary. You can as well manually resize the axis thanks to `xlim()` and `ylim()`

Comment: Oh, I've forgotten what my concern was before. It is necessary. Cause in my case the PDF the normalised number of particles of a certain diameter. But I wanna plot them along the position x, which has orders of magnitude difference as numbers.
So basically, I need the shape of the PDFs, proportionally correct size compared to each other. But then still x on the axis.